# Report Viewer - normal mode not same as print preview mode

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm using ReportViewer control for my reports and users demand search functionality, which Reportviewer allready has built-in, and also print "current page" functionality which Microsoft didn't include so I wrote It myself... Problem is that in Normal mode all linked data is combined in same page and in Print Preview pages have page break. This results in not same page numbers in Normal vs. Print Preview mode because ReportViewer renders differently when switching these modes. So when I try to print current page e.g. "19" in Normal mode I will get printed page "19" from Print Preview mode, and that is not same as what you see on screen.

Is there anything I can do - change .rdlc project in a way that Normal mode would break pages same as Print Preview does ? Or get a stream image of what I see on screen and print that out ?....Any help kindly appreciated, I'm struggling to find anything to solve this, but no success so far...

EDIT: My class for printing current page in ReportViewer. It might help someone, It works for Print Preview mode but not for Normal mode If your linked data is so big that pages have page break - because stream image which is used for printing current page actually copies what you have set in .rdlc report project - in my case A4 paper size:

```
class TiskanjeTrenutneStrani : PrintDocument
{
    private PageSettings nastavitve_strani;
    private int stran_za_tiskanje;
    private List<Stream> strani_reporta = new List<Stream>();

    public TiskanjeTrenutneStrani(LocalReport localReport, int stran)
        : this((Report)localReport)
    {
        //Set page for printing
        stran_za_tiskanje = stran-1;
        RenderirajStraniIzpisa(localReport);
    }

    private TiskanjeTrenutneStrani(Report report)
    {
        //Set page as defined in report project
        ReportPageSettings nastavitve_Report_Strani = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();
        var  nastavitve_strani = new PageSettings
        {
            PaperSize = nastavitve_Report_Strani.PaperSize,
            Margins = nastavitve_Report_Strani.Margins
        };
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (Stream s in strani_reporta)
            {
                s.Dispose();
            }

            strani_reporta.Clear();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPrintPage(e);

        Stream TiskanaStran = strani_reporta[stran_za_tiskanje];
        TiskanaStran.Position = 0;

        // Load each page into a Metafile to draw it.
        using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(TiskanaStran))
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                    e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height);


            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rc);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, rc);

        }
    }

    protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageSettings = (PageSettings)nastavitve_strani.Clone();
    }

    private void RenderirajStraniIzpisa(LocalReport localReport)
    {
        string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

        localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, out Warning[] warnings);
    }

    private Stream LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(string name, string extension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        strani_reporta.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    private string CreateEMFDeviceInfo()
    {
        PaperSize velikost_papirja = nastavitve_strani.PaperSize;
        Margins margins = nastavitve_strani.Margins;

        // The device info string defines the page range to print as well as the size of the page.
        // A start and end page of 0 means generate all pages.
        return
            string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><EndPage>0</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>",
        ToInches(margins.Top),
            ToInches(margins.Left),
            ToInches(margins.Right),
            ToInches(margins.Bottom),
            ToInches(velikost_papirja.Height),
            ToInches(velikost_papirja.Width));
    }

    private static string ToInches(int hundrethsOfInch)
    {
        double inches = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0;
        return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
  TiskanjeTrenutneStrani tiskaj_stran = new 
  TiskanjeTrenutneStrani(this.LocalReport, this.CurrentPage);
  tiskaj_stran.Print(); // And It prints current page - unfortunally not what you see on screen If in normal mode
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills, here is my code for printing current pages - If It helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Set the `StartPage` and `Endpage` in `DeviceInfo` to stran_za_tiskanje.

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>{6}</StartPage><EndPage>{6}</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>",
        ToInches(margins.Top),
            ToInches(margins.Left),
            ToInches(margins.Right),
            ToInches(margins.Bottom),
            ToInches(velikost_papirja.Height),
            ToInches(velikost_papirja.Width),
            stran_za_tiskanje);
```

Since you specified one page, you should only have one item to grab.

```
Stream TiskanaStran = strani_reporta[0];
```

Comment: thanks for response, but that doesn't solve It. I guess you didn't quite understood me - stream makes a copy of report as you see It in Print Preview, that is with page breaks If you have any. But when you are in Normal mode all pages with page break are joined in one page, that is different rendering, has something to do with faster "search" functionality. So when I'm printing page 6 in Normal mode I will get a copy of page 6 from Print Preview mode - and that could be different thing as you see on screen If some previous pages in report allready has page breaks.

Comment: I believe that solution would be to somehow figure page number of stream image for page that you're currently searching in Normal mode to tell what page should be printed from stream ...Or create different type of stream and print out only what you see on screen, regardless of report project page settings....